# What would cause this error nightly during NTBackup (SBS 2003)?

Tags: backup, windows-sbs-2003, windows-sbs-2011, ntbackup

I am getting the following warning message on 510 different files (always the same ones) every night:

WARNING: Portions of "[INSERT FILENAME HERE]" cannot be read. The backed up data is corrupt or incomplete. This file will not restore correctly.

I'm running SBS 2003 and the backups are being written to an external USB hard drive.

Some relevant information:

- The issue has been replicated on 3 different external hard drives. It is unlikely to be an issue with the storage media.
- The issue has been occurring for at least 2 months.
- The issue continued after running chkdsk on the drive
  vssadmin list writers (in command prompt) does not list any errors on any writers.
- .bkf files are created on the backup hard drive.I can successfully restore all files except the ones that had warnings. Files that had warnings will restore, but are damaged i.e. they won't open (the originals can be opened).
- Backups have completed successfully in the past.
- I recently changed hard drives because the old 500GB ones were near capacity (and backups had failed for that reason). The new drives that I'm using are 4TB. But the issue has occurred on both the old drives and the new drives.
- The server was also having another issue with its OS partition reaching capacity which was caused a bunch or problems. That problem was resolved by moving exchange databases to the data partition. The backup on the OS partition is and always has succeeded. It's the Data partition that produces the error. I suspect that the issue has to do with the fact that the server ran out of storage on its OS partition though, since that problem started approximately the same time (less than two months ago).

LOGS:

Here is the log from the chkdsk performed earlier this week.

```
Event Type: Information
Event Source:   Winlogon
Event Category: None
Event ID:   1001
Date:       10/1/2013
Time:       10:11:34 AM
User:       N/A
Computer:   MCIDDC01
Description:
Checking file system on D:
The type of the file system is NTFS.
Volume label is DATAPART1.

A disk check has been scheduled.
Windows will now check the disk.                         
Cleaning up 99 unused index entries from index $SII of file 0x9.
Cleaning up 99 unused index entries from index $SDH of file 0x9.
Cleaning up 99 unused security descriptors.
CHKDSK is verifying Usn Journal...
Usn Journal verification completed.
CHKDSK is verifying file data (stage 4 of 5)...
File data verification completed.
CHKDSK is verifying free space (stage 5 of 5)...
Free space verification is complete.

 455551996 KB total disk space.
 132079908 KB in 77441 files.
     40456 KB in 10492 indexes.
         0 KB in bad sectors.
    235104 KB in use by the system.
     65536 KB occupied by the log file.
 323196528 KB available on disk.

      4096 bytes in each allocation unit.
 113887999 total allocation units on disk.
  80799132 allocation units available on disk.

Internal Info:
40 6e 01 00 87 57 01 00 aa 4e 02 00 00 00 00 00  @n...W...N......
35 30 00 00 00 00 00 00 0a 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  50..............
48 db 71 06 00 00 00 00 5e d2 e9 58 00 00 00 00  H.q.....^..X....
e4 bf 18 07 00 00 00 00 80 d0 f2 08 04 00 00 00  ................
1a a9 b4 1e 00 00 00 00 2e 08 fc 96 04 00 00 00  ................
40 7f 44 6f 00 00 00 00 ad 9d 82 7c 6c 00 00 00  @.Do.......|l...
81 2e 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 90 84 7d 1f 00 00 00  ...........}....


For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
```

Here is the log from last night's backup. I have ommitted all of the error messages and left one generic one. They are all the same, but there are 510 of them.

```
10/3/2013 10:00 PM
-------------------------------
Date: 10/3/2013
Time: 10:00 PM
User: SYSTEM
-------------------------------

Backup Runner started.
Launching NTBackup: ntbackup.exe backup "@C:\Program Files\Microsoft Windows Small Business Server\Backup\Small Business Backup Script.bks" /d "SBS Backup created on 10/3/2013 at 10:00 PM" /v:yes /r:no /rs:no /hc:off /m normal /j "Small Business Server Backup Job" /l:s /f "F:\Backup Files\Small Business Server Backup (02).bkf" /UM
NTBACKUP LOG FILE: C:\Documents and Settings\SBS Backup User\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Windows NT\NTBackup\data\backup07.log
=====================<BEGIN NTBACKUP LOG FILE>=====================
Backup Status
Operation: Backup
Active backup destination: File
Media name: "Small Business Server Backup (02).bkf created 10/3/2013 at 10:00 PM"

Volume shadow copy creation: Attempt 1.
Backup (via shadow copy) of "C: OS"
Backup set #1 on media #1
Backup description: "SBS Backup created on 10/3/2013 at 10:00 PM"
Media name: "Small Business Server Backup (02).bkf created 10/3/2013 at 10:00 PM"

Backup Type: Normal

Backup started on 10/3/2013 at 10:05 PM.
Backup completed on 10/3/2013 at 10:48 PM.
Directories: 8603
Files: 92743
Bytes: 17,943,120,824
Time:  43 minutes and  10 seconds
Backup (via shadow copy) of "D: DATAPART1"
Backup set #2 on media #1
Backup description: "SBS Backup created on 10/3/2013 at 10:00 PM"
Media name: "Small Business Server Backup (02).bkf created 10/3/2013 at 10:00 PM"

Backup Type: Normal

Backup started on 10/3/2013 at 10:48 PM.
WARNING: Portions of "\Company\AutoCAD\Plotters\PMP Files\PublishToWeb JPG.pmp" cannot be read.  The backed up data is corrupt or incomplete. This file will not restore correctly.

Backup completed on 10/4/2013 at 2:11 AM.
Directories: 10523
Files: 77447
Corrupt: 510
Bytes: 134,959,355,310
Time:  3 hours,  22 minutes, and  44 seconds
Backup of "MCIDDC01\Microsoft Information Store\First Storage Group"
Backup set #3 on media #1
Backup description: "SBS Backup created on 10/3/2013 at 10:00 PM"
Media name: "Small Business Server Backup (02).bkf created 10/3/2013 at 10:00 PM"

Backup Type: Normal

Backup started on 10/4/2013 at 2:14 AM.
Backup completed on 10/4/2013 at 3:04 AM.
Directories: 4
Files: 9
Bytes: 23,915,045,974
Time:  50 minutes and  14 seconds
Backup (via shadow copy) of "System State"
Backup set #4 on media #1
Backup description: "SBS Backup created on 10/3/2013 at 10:00 PM"
Media name: "Small Business Server Backup (02).bkf created 10/3/2013 at 10:00 PM"

Backup Type: Copy

Backup started on 10/4/2013 at 3:07 AM.
Backup completed on 10/4/2013 at 3:09 AM.
Directories: 265
Files: 3110
Bytes: 638,357,758
Time:  2 minutes and  40 seconds

----------------------

Verify Status
Operation: Verify After Backup
Active backup destination: File
Active backup destination: F:\Backup Files\Small Business Server Backup (02).bkf

Verify of "C:"
Backup set #1 on media #1
Backup description: "SBS Backup created on 10/3/2013 at 10:00 PM"
Verify started on 10/4/2013 at 3:09 AM.
Verify completed on 10/4/2013 at 3:20 AM.
Directories: 8603
Files: 92743
Different: 0
Bytes: 17,943,120,824
Time:  10 minutes and  17 seconds

Verify of "D:"
Backup set #2 on media #1
Backup description: "SBS Backup created on 10/3/2013 at 10:00 PM"
Verify started on 10/4/2013 at 3:20 AM.
Verify completed on 10/4/2013 at 4:51 AM.
Directories: 10523
Files: 77447
Different: 0
Bytes: 134,959,355,310
Time:  1 hour,  31 minutes, and  4 seconds

Verify of "MCIDDC01\Microsoft Information Store\First Storage Group"
Backup set #3 on media #1
Backup description: "SBS Backup created on 10/3/2013 at 10:00 PM"
Verify started on 10/4/2013 at 4:51 AM.
Verify completed on 10/4/2013 at 5:13 AM.
Directories: 4
Files: 0
Different: 0
Bytes: 23,915,045,974
Time:  22 minutes and  6 seconds

Verify of "System State"
Backup set #4 on media #1
Backup description: "SBS Backup created on 10/3/2013 at 10:00 PM"
Verify started on 10/4/2013 at 5:13 AM.
Verify completed on 10/4/2013 at 5:13 AM.
Directories: 265
Files: 3110
Different: 0
Bytes: 638,357,758
Time:  37 seconds

----------------------

=======================<END NTBACKUP LOG FILE>=====================
NTBackup finished the backup with errors.

For more information about failed backups, see the article on troubleshooting your backup at the following Web page: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=18414

Backup ended at Friday, October 04, 2013 5:14 AM
Backup Runner finished.
```

Comment: I hate to say that it may be as simple as those files being bad. It's always the same files? Never any more or less?

Comment: @joeqwerty I looked into whether the files are always the same. There are small differences. The backup for 10/2/13's error messages are about 95% similar to 10/3/13. The backup for 9/27/13 is probably about 80% similar. This is what makes me think it isn't the files: 1) Some files that produced errors on 9/27/13 did not produce errors on 10/2/13 or 10/3/13. 2) I can open the files listed in the backup log. The only way I can't open them is if I try to restore a backed up version of the file (the original is still fine).